# Lottery entry for convention panels - grouping vs going solo

Tags: probability

The upcoming Star Wars convention in Chicago is testing out a new system that allows people to enter a lottery to try and get a seat at the big panels. This has lead to a lot of math and pseudo math as everyone argues about how best to game the system and whether it's fair or not.

I'd like to learn how, if at all, different possibilities of the system's configuration will alter the outcome.

Let's start with an audience of 70,000 people. There's only seating for 7,000 of them in the largest panel. Assuming everyone enters the lottery, the odds of any given person having a seat is 1:10, right?

Now let's add a grouping system. Instead of entering a lottery alone, you can also enter as a group of 2-6 people. If the group wins the lottery, everyone gets a seat. Each person may be a member of only one group. What would the likelihood be of a given person getting a seat if each group's entry counts as a single chance? What about if each group gets one entry per group member (but any one of them winning still means that everyone gets a seat?)

In a group setting, is there an optimal group size? In other words, can someone improve their odds by joining a group?